# The chance of winning exactly one prize after buying 5 tickets out of 80, with 3 tickets winning

Tags: probability

Five tickets are bought in a raffle containing eighty sold. There are three prizes. Tim buys five. What is the chance Tim wins exactly one prize? I've got the solution and answer manual, but don't want to spend all that time drawing tree diagrams etc.

Comment: What is the probability that he wins _just_ the first price? Now triple that.

Comment: You mean you would like strangers to spend their time drawing tree diagrams for your edification instead?

Comment: @DilipSarwate No I meant I want to find a quicker way - I already have the solutions and I forgot ot mention the answer: 17%

Comment: @Arthur My solution manual says 17% but I get 18.75 using your method%?

Comment: Then you're doing something wrong, because I get $16.89\%$.

Comment: @Arthur ok thanks I'll work on it again

Comment: @Arthur (5/80) * 3 * 100 = 18.75% ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability that the first prize is won is $5/80$. Now, the probability that *only* the first prize is won (that is, the first prize is won, and at the same time the second and third are lost) is
$$
\frac{5}{80}\cdot \frac{75}{79}\cdot \frac{74}{78} = 0.0563 = 5.63\%
$$
The probability that *only the second prize* is won is
$$
\frac{75}{80}\cdot \frac{5}{79}\cdot \frac{74}{78}
$$
which you can see has exactly the same result. And finally, the probability of winning *only the third prize* is
$$
\frac{75}{80}\cdot \frac{74}{79}\cdot \frac{5}{78}
$$
which again has the exact same answer. All together, the probability that one of these three events occur (seing as how they *cannot* occur together, and are therefore disjoint) is just
$$
3\cdot 5.63\% = 16.89\%
$$

Comment: Makes sense now, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can look at it from a combinatorial point of view:

There are $\binom{3}{1}$ ways of picking one of the three prizes, and $\binom{77}{4}$ ways of choosing the remaining 4 tickets from the remaining non-winning tickets.
Multiply these together and divide by the total number of ways he can choose 5 tickets, i.e. $\binom{80}{5}$

So the answer is $\frac {2775}{16432}$

Comment: That's interesting. I've never done combinatorics though. Do you think it's worth learning if I want to solve just these type of questions? I'm still doing precalc..

Comment: Yes definitely. In many cases it saves drawing those pesky tree diagrams!

Comment: wow thanks, I'll note that down in my book. Cheers